# How to do Retopology using fixed size faces aligned to curved edges of underlying mesh

Tags: retopology, remesh

I am trying to manually retopo a mesh, because I want to make sure the seams of the chair are covered by faces that are oriented along the seams/visible stitches.

This is my first venture into retopo (I did experiment a bit with the remesh modifier, but afaik that does not give me any control on the face orientation in the result).

I am struggling with (at least :) ) two things

1. Get a nice smooth curve along the edges of the underlying high poly mesh of the chair at the location of the seams - I am using BSurface mesh tool, using annotate pen to draw the lines, but this results in wobbles and uneven width of the strip
2. I want the faces to be about 10 mm wide, so 2 of them cover the seam/stitches. How can I make sure that the faces are 10mm (ideally in both directions, but at least across the width of the strip)

I did manage to UV unwrap a test kube to get stitches along the edges, but that was easy because all faces were already oriented correctly alongside the seam/stitch direction.

[image: Example of manually added face strip]

[image: Photo of the top of the chair I am modelling]

[image: Sample Cube showing the intended result]